# JavaScript Integer math incorrect results

Tags: javascript, integer, overflow

I am just trying to implement a simple RNG in JS.

What's happening is javascript evaluates `119106029 * 1103515245` to be `131435318772912110` rather than `131435318772912105`. We know it's wrong since two odd numbers multiplied does not give an even number.

Anyone know what's up? I just want a reliable repeatable RNG, and because of these incorrect values I can't get results to match up with my C implementation of the same thing.

Comment: If I were you I'd be asking: Why do you need to multiply such huge numbers in the first place? The might be a way to do what you want without using this method. 

Unless its some scientific problem domain, you could have a design fault.

Comment: Just making the simplest random number generator ever. Multiply by large number, add a constant, mod by 2**32. I am only interested in the last couple of bits! But theyre wrong. Why?

Comment: For times when `Math.random() * 100000(00.....)` isn't enough!?

Comment: See Jason's answer. I need something deterministic and reproducible. I want a particular seed value to give me a particular random sequence that I can replicate.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Per the ECMAScript standard, all numbers in JavaScript are (64-bit IEEE 754) floating-point numbers by default.

However all 32-bit integers can be exactly represented as floating-point numbers. You can force a result to 32 bits by using the appropriate bitwise operator, like this:

```
x = (a * b) >>> 0;  // force to unsigned int32
x = (a * b) | 0;    // force to signed int32
```

Weird, but that's the standard.

(Incidentally this rounding behavior is [one of the most frequently reported "bugs"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5856) against Firefox's JavaScript engine. Looks like it's been reported 3 times so far this year...)

If you want real integer math, you can use `BigInt` values, a different type of number, written with an `n` at the end:

```
> 119106029n * 1103515245n
131435318772912105n
```

This is a relatively recent JS feature, and may not be implemented in old browsers.

---

As for reproducible random numbers in JavaScript, the V8 benchmark uses this:

```
// To make the benchmark results predictable, we replace Math.random
// with a 100% deterministic alternative.
Math.random = (function() {
  var seed = 49734321;
  return function() {
    // Robert Jenkins' 32 bit integer hash function.
    seed = ((seed + 0x7ed55d16) + (seed << 12))  & 0xffffffff;
    seed = ((seed ^ 0xc761c23c) ^ (seed >>> 19)) & 0xffffffff;
    seed = ((seed + 0x165667b1) + (seed << 5))   & 0xffffffff;
    seed = ((seed + 0xd3a2646c) ^ (seed << 9))   & 0xffffffff;
    seed = ((seed + 0xfd7046c5) + (seed << 3))   & 0xffffffff;
    seed = ((seed ^ 0xb55a4f09) ^ (seed >>> 16)) & 0xffffffff;
    return (seed & 0xfffffff) / 0x10000000;
  };
})();
```

Comment: IIRC I did use either this or some other variant of a Robert Jenkins PRNG in my application ([htmltetris.com](http://htmltetris.com))

Comment: As an alternative to BigInt, since the OP says they only want the low bits of the result to be correct, there is [Math.imul](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/imul) for multiplying 32-bit integer values.

Answer (score 3):

When an integer in javascript is too big to fit in a 32 bit value, some browsers will convert it to a floating point. Since the value of floating points is only save to a limited precision, some rounding can occur on big values.

Comment: The result is correct to the last two bits though. It would make sense if it just truncates upper bits but all I want is the lower 32 bits of the result anyway. How do I get that?

Comment: @Steven: Javascript doesn't really have an integer type, in this case you're seeing precision loss in floating point numbers. And those retain the "upper part" of the number, not the low bits (like integer multiplication would do).

Answer (score 2):

If done in C/C++ (double), the last numbers will be ...112
instead of 105 (which is correct). If performed with 'long double',
the result will be as expected (...105). So it looks like the
Javascript interpreter converts the numbers to 8-byte-double
internally, does the calculation and does some unknown rounding
which leads to a marginally better result than the C/C++ standard
double calculation.

GCC 4.5:

```
 int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 long double a = 119106029;
 long double b = 1103515245;
 long double c = a * b;
 printf("%.Lf\n", c);

 return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
131435318772912105
```

Expected:

```
131435318772912105
```

So I don't see a chance in Javascript without the
aid of a BIGNUM library (if any).

Regards

rbo

Answer (score 1):

With the arrival of BigInt, you can now perform these calculations with accuracy:

```js
console.log((119106029n * 1103515245n).toString());
```