# Split decimal variable into integral and fraction parts

Tags: c#, decimal, fractions, integral

I am trying to extract the integral and fractional parts from a decimal value (both parts should be integers):

```
decimal decimalValue = 12.34m;
int integral = (int) decimal.Truncate(decimalValue);
int fraction = (int) ((decimalValue - decimal.Truncate(decimalValue)) * 100);
```

(for my purpose, decimal variables will contain up to 2 decimal places)

Are there any better ways to achieve this?

Comment: A better approach may be not to use a decimal at all, but use an `int`/`long` representing "your value multipled by 100".

Comment: Beware of unusual values. The max value for a decimal is ~7.9e28. The max value for an int is ~2e9 (significantly smaller). Even long only goes to ~9e18. So if you know the value will always be >= 0 you can use a ulong which goes all the way to ~18e18, giving a bit more leeway.

Comment: Following answer of a similar question may suits those needs for fractional part: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13038524/1178314

Answer (score 31):

```
       decimal fraction = (decimal)2.78;
        int iPart = (int)fraction;
        decimal dPart = fraction % 1.0m;
```

Comment: Very good use of modulus operator on decimal. I did not expect this to work, but it does beautifully (and it's fast) :)

Comment: I second @GoneCoding but the OP mentions "_both parts should be integers_".

Comment: @GeroldBroserreinstatesMonica Regarding the `dPart` variable, you can simply cast it as `integer`.

Comment: Not working if integer part is bigger that Int32.MaxValue

Answer (score 4):

Try mathematical definition:

```
var fraction = (int)(100.0m * (decimalValue - Math.Floor(decimalValue)));
```

Although, it is not better performance-wise but at least it works for negative numbers.

Comment: Try to use this:
var FileMinorPartClient = (int)(100.0m * (clientFileVersion - Math.Floor(clientFileVersion)));
I get:
"Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'double'"
(clientFileVersion is a double, a la 1.4)

Comment: @B.ClayShannon It says so because you cannot mix those two. Either change `100.0m` to `100.0` or make sure `decimalValue` is of `decimal` type

Answer (score 3):

```
decimal fraction = doubleNumber - Math.Floor(doubleNumber)
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
int fraction = (int) ((decimalValue - integral) * 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

For taking out fraction you can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4667302/698127):

```
Math.ceil(((f < 1.0) ? f : (f % Math.floor(f))) * 10000)
```