# Get the decimal part from a double

Tags: c#, .net

I want to receive the number after the decimal dot in the form of an integer. For example, only 05 from 1.05 or from 2.50 only 50 **not** 0.50

Comment: 2.50 is just 2.5. I assume you're talking of strings.

Comment: Are you always returning the first two digits after the decimal place? Is the input a `decimal`, `float`, `string`, ...?

Comment: An example of usages goes a long way toward getting quality answers, for next time.

Comment: yes only towo digits ,the input is decimal

Comment: Why not use `int y = value.Split('.')[1];`?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge, `.` is different in some countries.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge also performing split would take more time than mathematical expressions

Comment: The C# development team should be embarrassed (and take action) that this very common operation has no single Math.function such as Math.DecimalPart(double x) or something.    There is way too much "did you try this, did you think about that" for something many of us need to do often.

Comment: Meta observation: Not getting a "0.50" but getting a *number* of "50" from "2.50", or getting a *number* of "05" is one of the most ill-specified requirements I heard or read today.. not mentioning misleading title of the question. That being said, it's interesting how many of the answers focus on  the title and focus on how to calculate the non-integral part of a floating number, *completely ignoring* that the actual question includes *quite specific* formatting requirements :) Congrats to **orad** for answering in full.

Answer (score 246):

the best of the best way is:

```
var floatNumber = 12.5523;

var x = floatNumber - Math.Truncate(floatNumber);
```

result you can convert however you like

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, a Math solution to a Math question, without all that tedious mucking about in string manipulation

Comment: I think this solution have a "problem". If the floatNumber was "10.2", the variable x will be something like "0.19999999999999929". Even if this works as expected, the result would be "0.2" and not "2".

Comment: @Dherik Float and Double values always have small errors under subtraction in the last few decimal places.  You should not be considering those as significant.  If you actually need that kind of precision, you should be using Decimal type.  If you can't switch to Decimal (or just don't want to), then you ought to keep track of the expected precision somehow and account for that in comparison operations.  I usually use 4 decimal places, but there may be exceptions to that.

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Precision : "Because some numbers cannot be represented exactly as fractional binary values, floating-point numbers can only approximate real numbers"

Comment: Final comment: Using Math.Truncate was the intent of the author's of the Math library for this kind of situation.  @Matterai 's answer should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 88):

```
var decPlaces = (int)(((decimal)number % 1) * 100);
```

This presumes your number only has two decimal places.

Comment: `(318.40d % 1) * 100` outputs `39.9999999999977`, you can use casting to get around the rounding error: `var decPlaces = (int)(((decimal)number % 1) * 100);`

Comment: @orad Good call there - floating point numbers always have these little inaccuracies, so casting it is pretty prudent to ensure consistent behavior.  I'll update my answer, though Matterai's is still more technically correct.

Answer (score 66):

There is a cleaner and ways faster solution than the 'Math.Truncate' approach:

```
double frac = value % 1;
```

Comment: a note: **for negative values, it is negative**:
-12.34 % 1 => -0.33999999999999986

Answer (score 19):

**Solution without rounding problem:**

```
double number = 10.20;
var first2DecimalPlaces = (int)(((decimal)number % 1) * 100);
Console.Write("{0:00}", first2DecimalPlaces);
```

**Outputs:** `20`

> Note if we did not cast to decimal, it would output `19`.

Also:

- for `318.40` outputs: `40` (instead of `39`)
- for `47.612345` outputs: `61` (instead of `612345`)
- for `3.01` outputs: `01` (instead of `1`)

> If you are working with financial numbers, for example if in this case you are trying to get the *cents* part of a transaction amount, always use the `decimal` data type.

**Update:**

The following will also work if processing it as a string (building on @SearchForKnowledge's answer).

```
10.2d.ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Split('.')[1]
```

You can then use `Int32.Parse` to convert it to int.

Comment: Thumbs up for mod ones

Comment: I used this...10.2d.ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Split('.')[1]

Answer (score 11):

**Better Way -**

```
        double value = 10.567;
        int result = (int)((value - (int)value) * 100);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output -**

```
56
```

Comment: Did not test, but this suffers from float inaccuracy, no?

Comment: For `10.20` it will output `19`. See my answer.

Answer (score 9):

The simplest variant is possibly with Math.truncate()

```
double value = 1.761
double decPart = value - Math.truncate(value)
```

Comment: does not work for value below zero like 0.25

Answer (score 4):

I guess this thread is getting old but I can't believe nobody has mentioned Math.Floor

```
//will always be .02 cents
(10.02m - System.Math.Floor(10.02m))
```

Comment: For the super lazy:
`double fract(double x) { return x - System.Math.Floor(x); }`

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = number.ToString().Split(System.Globalization.NumberDecimalSeparator)[2]
```

Returns it as a string (but you can always cast that back to an int), and assumes the number does have a "." somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
int last2digits = num - (int) ((double) (num /  100) * 100);
```

Comment: Question is to get first 2 decimal digits. For number `318.401567d` your solution outputs `0.401567` where `40` is expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static string FractionPart(this double instance)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;
        var ic = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        var splits = instance.ToString(ic).Split(new[] { ic.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (splits.Count() > 1)
        {
            result = splits[1];
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 string input = "0.55";
    var regex1 = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(?<=[\\.])[0-9]+");
    if (regex1.IsMatch(input))
    {
        string dp= regex1.Match(input ).Value;
    }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could add a description on how the regex helps solving the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = 1.5;
var decimalPart = Convert.ToInt32(d.ToString().Split('.')[1]);
```

it gives you `5` from `1.5` :)

Comment: This will give you `25` for `0.25` though

Comment: @mousetail as the question wants :)

Comment: No, he wants 50 for 0.5

Comment: @mousetail no, he wants `50` from `2.50`

Comment: There is no difference between 2.5 and 2.50

Comment: its from the question: `For example, only 05 from 1.05 or from 2.50 only 50 not 0.50`

Answer (score -1):

You may remove the dot `.` from the double you are trying to get the decimals from using the `Remove()` function after converting the double to string so that you could do the operations required on it

Consider having a double `_Double` of value of `0.66781`, the following code will only show the numbers after the dot `.` which are `66781`

```
double _Double = 0.66781; //Declare a new double with a value of 0.66781
string _Decimals = _Double.ToString().Remove(0, _Double.ToString().IndexOf(".") + 1); //Remove everything starting with index 0 and ending at the index of ([the dot .] + 1)
```

**Another Solution**

You may use the class `Path` as well which performs operations on string instances in a cross-platform manner

```
double _Double = 0.66781; //Declare a new double with a value of 0.66781
string Output = Path.GetExtension(D.ToString()).Replace(".",""); //Get (the dot and the content after the last dot available and replace the dot with nothing) as a new string object Output
//Do something
```

Answer (score -1):

In my tests this was 3-4 times slower than the Math.Truncate answer, but only one function call. Perhaps someone likes it:

```
var float_number = 12.345;
var x = Math.IEEERemainder(float_number , 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

My answer is based on a suspected use-case behind this question and people coming to this question.

The following example program will display a decimal value in a way that appears like a currency like 34.99 or 1.00 unless it has further precision, in which case it will display the whole precision like, 290.19882 or 128.00001

Please critique. Remember the design is for display.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ConvertToString(5.00m));
        Console.WriteLine(ConvertToString(5.01m));
        Console.WriteLine(ConvertToString(5.99m));
        Console.WriteLine(ConvertToString(5.000000191m));
        Console.WriteLine(ConvertToString(5.000000191000m));
        Console.WriteLine(ConvertToString(51028931298373.000000191000m));
    }

    public static string ConvertToString(decimal value)
    {
        decimal whole = Math.Truncate(value);
        decimal fractional = value - whole;
        return ConvertToString(whole, fractional);
    }

    public static string ConvertToString(decimal whole, decimal fractional)
    {
        if (fractional == 0m)
        {
            return $"{whole:F0}.00";
        }
        else
        {
            string fs = fractional.ToString("F28").Substring(2).TrimEnd('0');
            return $"{whole:F0}.{fs}";
        }
    }
}
```

Results

```
5.00
5.01
5.99
5.000000191
5.000000191
51028931298373.000000191
```

Answer (score -2):

Use a regex: `Regex.Match("\.(?\d+)")` Someone correct me if I'm wrong here

Comment: Not very popular with `Regex.Match` but I've received the following error when trying to get the value of the decimal
`ArgumentException was unhandled: parsing "\.(?\d+)" - Unrecognized grouping construct.`

Answer (score -2):

It is very simple

```
       float moveWater =  Mathf.PingPong(theTime * speed, 100) * .015f;
       int    m = (int)(moveWater);
       float decimalPart= moveWater -m ;

       Debug.Log(decimalPart);
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not use `int y = value.Split('.')[1];`?

The `Split()` function splits the value into separate content and the `1` is outputting the 2nd value after the `.`

Comment: This will work: `Int32.Parse((12.05123d.ToString("0.00").Split('.')[1]))`

Comment: Because you are casting it to a string to do string manipulation. I don't think you realize just how slow and wasteful this is.