# C# Extract Decimal number with out period

Tags: c#, regex

I need to extract a decimal number from string. Currently I am using this regex to find a decimal number but it need a proper decimal value.

```
 var value = Regex.Match(formula, @"(?n)\d+(\.(?<decimal>\d+))?");
            return value.Groups["decimal"].Success ? int.Parse(value.Groups["decimal"].Value) : 0;
```

if I write `2.1` it gives me `1` but when write `.1` it doesn't evaluate that string.

I need to extract a decimal number from these string with one regex

```
2.1 = 1
.5 = 5
SMA(21).6 = 6
```

How to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the decimal part from a double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038482/get-the-decimal-part-from-a-double)

Comment: Why is `SMA(21).6` a number? Are there any other peculiar test cases?

Comment: @JericCruz Not at all

Comment: actually, I just need decimal number only. which is .6 in this case. I need only 6 with out period.

Comment: Yes... Try a naive [`@"\.(?<decimal>\d+)"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c.%28%5cd%2b%29&i=2.1+%3d+1%0d%0a.5+%3d+5%0d%0aSMA%2821%29.6+%3d+6), or a more complex [`@"(?n)(\([A-Z]+\)|\d|\B)\.(?<decimal>\d+)"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fn%29%28%5c%28%5bA-Z%5d%2b%5c%29%7c%5cd%7c%5cB%29%5c.%28%3f%3cdecimal%3e%5cd%2b%29&i=2.1+%3d+1%0d%0a.5+%3d+5%0d%0aSMA%2821%29.6+%3d+6)

Comment: and yes there are many test cases in which I follow the same pattern of writing string. Like SMA(21).6, TMF(21).5, EMA(29).45 etc

Comment: how to avoid . using this regex \.(\d+)?

Comment: `var res = Regex.Match(formula, @"\.(\d+)").Groups[1].Value;` or `var res = Regex.Match(formula, @"\.(?<decimal>\d+)").Groups["decimal"].Value;`

Comment: or look behind `(?<=\.)(\d+)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks very much its exactly what I needed

Comment: I posted the solution. Please remove the first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just want to extract 1 or more digits after a dot. You may use a simple `\.(\d+)` regex that matches a literal dot and then matches *and captures* 1 or more digits into Group 1.

Use

```
var m = Regex.Match(formula, @"\.(\d+)");
var res = string.Empty;
if (m.Success)
{ 
    res = m.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C.%28%5Cd%2B%29&i=2.1%20%3D%201%0D%0A.5%20%3D%205%0D%0ASMA%2821%29.6%20%3D%206)

[image]

Comment: I have another situation in which I need to extract string followed which sometimes contain a decimal number and sometimes not. I have two string like this
MACD(C,26,12,9)
SMA(C,26,12,9).1

when i use this regex  (MACD)\([^()]*\)\.(?<decimal>\d+) its only select one with decimal number  but I want to select both. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to be specific. If you need to specify exact context (match `.` after `MACD`, `SMA` (Forex terms, I know)), you need to use alternation: [`@"(?n)\b(MACD|SMA)\([^()]*\)\.(?<decimal>\d+)"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28MACD%7cSMA%29%5c%28%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%5c%29%5c.%28%3f%3cdecimal%3e%5cd%2b%29&i=MACD%28C%2c26%2c12%2c9%29.12+SMA%28C%2c26%2c12%2c9%29.1&o=n).

Comment: its only select SMA string but not MACD string. Do I need to use OR condition to select both?

Comment: Your `MACD(C,26,12,9)` has no period. How come you want it to be matched?

Comment: that's what I mentioned that I wanted to select both sometime string have period and sometimes not

Comment: period is optional

Comment: Then use `\b(MACD|SMA)\([^()]*\)(\.(?<decimal>\d+))?`