# How to show just a part of the number

Tags: c#, helper

I have the number 0.15 but I only want to show 15.
How do I do that?
*I need the solution to match every number (ex: 0.234 to 234, 0.3 to 3 etc...)
Thanks for the helpers...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the decimal part from a double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038482/get-the-decimal-part-from-a-double)

Comment: Did you even try anything? There are plenty of similar questions around. Anyway: what if your number is greater 1? Do you want only the decimal part (as the duplicate assumes), or what else?

Comment: Also, are you working with strings or numbers? Do you want your output as string or as a number?

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
class Program
{        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double number = 1.234;
        number = GetDecimalPart(number);

        float number1 = 1.234f;
        number1 = GetDecimalPart(number1);

        decimal number2 = 1.234m;
        number2 = GetDecimalPart(number2);
    }

    private static double GetDecimalPart(double number)
    {
        string strNumber = number.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        strNumber = strNumber.Substring(strNumber.IndexOf(".") + 1);
        return double.Parse(strNumber);
    }

    private static float GetDecimalPart(float number)
    {
        string strNumber = number.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        strNumber = strNumber.Substring(strNumber.IndexOf(".") + 1);
        return float.Parse(strNumber);
    }

    private static decimal GetDecimalPart(decimal number)
    {
        string strNumber = number.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        strNumber = strNumber.Substring(strNumber.IndexOf(".") + 1);
        return decimal.Parse(strNumber);
    }
}
```