# C# decimal format to display just the fraction part

Tags: c#, string.format

I'm looking to `String.Format` or `ToString()` a `decimal` to get just the fraction part.
`'123.56m => "56"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I display a decimal value to 2 decimal places?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164926/how-do-i-display-a-decimal-value-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: @T1Space Why do _you_ think it does answer the question?

Comment: There isn't any Numeric Custom Format specifier for only the fractional part, but if you do some arithmetic first you can extract it _then_ format it.

Comment: @T1Space Unfortunately not. It will not remove the whole part of the value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [Unfortunately there isn't any Numeric Custom Format specifier for only the fractional part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings), but [if you do some arithmetic first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038482/get-the-decimal-part-from-a-double) you can extract it *then* format it...

  - ...and you'll need a `.Substring` call too.
- Also, be sure to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, otherwise per-user language/culture/region settings will mean possibly different default formatting and radix-point (decimal-point) chars will be used, but using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` means the radix-point will *always* be an ASCII dot `'.'` char.
- I did try an approach using `IFormatProvider` and `ICustomFormatter`, unfortunately `Decimal.ToString(IFormatProvider)` *requires* `provider`.GetFormat to return a `NumberFormatInfo` value and doesn't support using `ICustomFormatter`.

  - Though `IFormatProvider` and `ICustomFormatter` will work if used with `String.Format`, but that's not in your question.

---

- Using `Math.Abs()` to convert negative numbers to positive numbers (otherwise there's a leading `-` sign char which would complicate the `.Substring` call-site).
- Using `".############################"` as the format-string corresponds to the maximum number of decimal places in a `Decimal` value (i.e. 28 digits).

  - The leading `.` part is necessary.
- When the `fractionalPart` is `0` then there are no digits to render and `.ToString( format: "#.########", provider: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture )` will return `""` (which will cause `.Substring( startIndex: 1 )` to throw an exception, so we can skip that with a ternary expression).

```cs
Decimal dec            = 123.45M;
Decimal fractionalPart = Math.Abs( dec - Decimal.Truncate( dec ) );

String formatted       = fractionalPart.ToString( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, ".############################" );

if( formatted.StartsWith( '.' ) ) formatted = formatted.Substring( startIndex: 1 );

Console.WriteLine( "{0} --> \"{1}\"", dec, formatted ); // "123.45 --> 45"
```

You can simplify it down to 2 lines:

```cs
Decimal fractionalPart = Math.Abs( value - Decimal.Truncate( value ) );
return ( fractionalPart == 0 ) ? String.Empty : fractionalPart.ToString( format: ".############################", provider: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ).Substring( startIndex: 1 );
```

---

Examples:

```cs
static String FmtOnlyFractional( Decimal value )
{
    Decimal fractionalPart = Math.Abs( value - Decimal.Truncate( value ) );
    return ( fractionalPart == 0 ) ? String.Empty : fractionalPart.ToString( format: ".############################", provider: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ).Substring( startIndex: 1 );
}

FmtOnlyFractional(    0.0M        ); => ""
FmtOnlyFractional(    1.0M        ); => ""
FmtOnlyFractional(    1.1M        ); => "1"
FmtOnlyFractional4(   1.0010000M  ); => "001"
FmtOnlyFractional(    0.00000001M ); => "00000001"
FmtOnlyFractional(  123.00000001M ); => "00000001"
FmtOnlyFractional( -123.00000001M ); => "00000001"
FmtOnlyFractional(   -0.00000001M ); => "00000001"
FmtOnlyFractional(   -1.0000000M  ); => ""
FmtOnlyFractional(   -1.0000001M  ); => "000001"
FmtOnlyFractional(   -1.1000001M  ); => "100001"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach assuming you have up to 2 digits fraction

```
decimal value = 123.56m;
string result = (value % 1 * 100).ToString("F0"); //"56"
```

---

string `Split()` approach

```
decimal value = 123.56m;
char separator = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CurrencyDecimalSeparator.First();
string result = value.ToString("F2").Split(separator ).Last();
```

Comment: You can get the decimal digits count as from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477689/find-number-of-decimal-places-in-decimal-value-regardless-of-culture then multiply per Math.Pow(10, digitscount).