# Time scaled from 0 to 1 in HH:MM

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

I have a simple question (I am bad at math...).
So i made a day/night cycle in my game and to change the time of the day i have slider ranging from 0 to 1. Everything is working correctly, but i can't convert this time in minutes.

Here is a bit of the code I am using:

Where **time** is my *slider* *(float)* and **timeRate** *(float)* a *time multiplier*.

```
    private void Update(){
        time += timeRate * Time.deltaTime;
        ConvertTime();
    }


    private void ConvertTime()
    {
        hours = 24 * time;
        minutes = ?;

        if(minutes >= 60)
            minutes = 0;

        displayRealTime = LeadingZero(hours.ToString("0")) + ":" + "00";
    }
```

*The "LeadingZero" function just add a 0 if the number < 10.*

The hours are good but i don't know how to get the minutes.
**Thanks for reading.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well your `hours` already contain the `minutes` after the decimal.

E.g.

```
12.23 hours
```

=> minutes is

```
0.23 * 60
```

So all you need is [Get only decimals of a floating point number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038482/get-the-decimal-part-from-a-double) and multiply it by `60` and then round to `int` again

```
var minutes = Mathf.RountToInt((hours % 1f) * 60f);
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sBMTq6)

Comment: Yeah that was a dumb question... But thanks for your time it work.