# JavaScript / reactJS - round up last decimal (without hardcoded decimal to calculate)

Tags: javascript

By using JavaScript to calculate, For Example (in live can be any value)

```
1000/0.997 = 1003.0090270812437
```

By using PC calculator to calculate

```
1000/0.997 = 1003.009027081244 // auto round up last decimal
```

[image]

**But if !!!**
this is correct and same as window, in this situation no need round up

```
500/0.997 = 501.5045135406219 // this is correct and same as window calculator
```

[image]

My prefer output is the auto round up value `1003.009027081244`

Question: In JavaScript, how to round up the last digit of decimal?

What I have tried:

```
Math.round(1003.0090270812437) // 1003
```

Comment: This would do the job `+(1000/0.997).toFixed(12)`

Comment: @Wazeed your suggestion is hardcoded `12` , have to avoid hardcoded

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = Number((1000/0.997).toPrecision(16))
```

```js
const result = Number((1000 / 0.997).toPrecision(16))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: why using `16` ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision

Comment: how do you know taking `16` as value ?

Comment: because in live example, will facing any number with different decimal, and needed to auto round up last decimal, `16` is kind a hardcode

Comment: @FeelRightz, Microsoft Windows OS Calc application is giving 16 precision results. Hence to get the same results as Windows OS Calc in Javascript, this can be used. 1054/100, for this Calc will not perform round-up for last decimal

Comment: @Wazeed how to get `16` ? or dynamic get `16` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no nice javascript way that I know to achieve this. Due to my knowledge this is the way to go:

```
Math.round(1003.0090270812437*1000000000000)/1000000000000
```

**Edit:**
If you do not want to round to a fixed number of decimals, then I would write a little function to count the given decimals before to know your exponent of 10:

```
var countDecimals = function(value) {
    if (Math.floor(value) !== value)
        return value.toString().split(".")[1].length || 0;
    return 0;
}

var temp = Math.pow(10, countDecimals-1);
Math.round(1003.0090270812437*temp)/temp;
```

Comment: yes, unless you know is using `1000000000000`

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: playing with numbers and decimals

```
const countDecimals = value => {
  let text = value.toString()
  if (text.indexOf('e-') > -1) {
    let [base, trail] = text.split('e-')
    let deg = parseInt(trail, 10)
    return deg - 1
  }

  if (Math.floor(value) !== value) return value.toString().split(".")[1].length - 1 || 0

  return 0
}
const round = number => Math.round(number * Math.pow(10, countDecimals(number - 1))) / Math.pow(10, countDecimals(number - 1))
```

Option 2: playing with strings

```
let round = number => {
  let str = (number).toString()
  let [num, dec] = str.split(".")
  let leading_zeros = ""
  for (const char of dec) {
    if (char !== '0') break
    leading_zeros += '0'
  }
  dec = Math.round(parseFloat(dec.substring(0, dec.length - 1) + "." + dec[dec.length - 1])).toString()
  return parseFloat(num + "." + leading_zeros + dec)
}
```

Comment: how to get decimal place ? because it can be any decimal place

Comment: @FeelRightz https://stackoverflow.com/a/27082406/12182781

Comment: By combining my rounding function and @Alex Filatov 's decimal counting function you can solve your problem.

Comment: @FeelRightz there I did the integration for you.

Comment: i try using `1003.0090270812437` , output still `1003.0090270812437`

Comment: and what do you want the output to be?

Comment: `1003.009027081244` as question explained

Comment: can you explain why need to deduct 1 ?

Comment: Because you want to round up the second last decimal place, you need to round to the N-1 decimal place not to Nth decimal place since rounding up to the Nth decimal place will just return the input. You can now do something yourself and modify the code so that you can round up to N - M decimal places. Now give me my reputation and have a nice day.

Comment: thx for your answer, but it wont work if `500/0.997`, see my updated question

Comment: I just thought of another way to do this using strings. convert float to string, get the second string (decimal numbers), add a decimal on the N-1 place so if you had 123.4567 now your decimal string is 456.7 then you convert decimal string to float and round it, then convert it back to a string, add it to 123 and add a decimal between both to get 123.457 and convert that string to float.

Comment: `501.5045135406219` is correct and no need to do anything, but `1003.0090270812437` need to be roundup

Comment: `501.5045135406219` last digit is 9, but no need round up

Comment: I added another option

Comment: option 2 , sadly if `1000/0.997` , wont work

Comment: Try the new edit solution should work for both cases

Comment: wont work on `500/0.997`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237961/discussion-between-dimitar-veljanovski-and-feelrightz).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use string based solution

Convert a decimal number to string, then `split` it by the `.`.
Then take a decimal part length substracted by 1, and use it in `toFixed` on the original number.

You will probably need some additional checks, to see if there is a decimal part of a number

```js
const decimal = 1003.0090270812437;
const text = decimal.toString().split('.')[1];

console.log(decimal.toFixed(text.length - 1)); // 1003.009027081244
```

Comment: this wont work if calculation go to `500/0.997`, see my question

Comment: Please update a question title. You don't want a last digit rounded up. You want a PC calculator behaviour of rounding up numbers

Answer (score -1):

You can just use `toFixed(${Amount of decimals you want to show})`

Example:
`(2321/912).toFixed(1)` will show one fraction of the decimal number

`(2322/ 1232).toFixed((2322/ 1232).toString().length - 1 )` will round you up the last digit