# Condition of if function is true. Still, if function is returning the value which needed to have been returned on condition being false

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In the below code (for custom function in google sheets made via google-apps-script) for AMin1(499.2, 510, 300),  I expected "Move to Higher Print Size" as the output; google sheets is giving 20 as the output. I checked bing copilot, I couldn't get answer. I tried [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlesheets/comments/18jlupf/i_am_not_able_to_find_error_in_this_apps_script/), couldn't get answer yet.

```
function AMin1(A,PD1,Min1) {
let L1;
L1=A+20;
while(L1<Min1) {
  L1=L1+A;
}   
if (L1>PD1) {L1=L1-A;}
if (L1==20) {return "Move to Higher Print Size";}
else {return L1;}
}
```

Comment: Arithmetic with non-integers does not always exact. It may not return a whole decimal number, even if the exact result would be one. In your case, `L1 = 20.000000000000057`. Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: Decimal Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454965/javascript-decimal-values)

Comment: Yeah, thank you; seems to be answering my question. I need to find alternative way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just encountered floating point precision issues in javascript. Check here: [How can I deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-can-i-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

One way to solve it is to sanitize your numbers with toFixed(). There're many other ways though:

```js
function AMin1(A,PD1,Min1) {
let L1;
L1=(A+20).toFixed(2);console.log("L1 b4", L1)
while(L1<Min1) {
  L1=L1+A;
L1=A+20;console.log("L1 after", L1)
}   
if (L1>PD1) {L1=(L1-A).toFixed(2);console.log("L1 after", L1)}
if (L1==20) {return "Move to Higher Print Size";}
else {return L1;}
}

console.log(AMin1(499.2, 510, 300));
```