# Different calculation outcome in JavaScript than in Java

Tags: java, javascript, math

I've a problem with large numbers I think.

The calculation in Java:

```
int n = 4451 + 554 * 57;
n = n << 13 ^ n;
System.out.println(n * (n * n * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589);
=> 587046333
```

In JavaScript:

```
var n = 4451 + 554 * 57;
n = n << 13 ^ n;
console.log(n * (n * n * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589);
=> 4.043454188561781e+29
```

What is the problem in the JavaScript version and how can I fix it, so that the outcome of JavaScript is identical to the Java outcome?

EDIT: tried with: https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum, but outcome is 0

```
var test = new BigInteger(295120061).multiply( new BigInteger(295120061) 
                                      .multiply(new BigInteger(295120061)) 
                                      .multiply(new BigInteger(15731)) 
                                      .add(new BigInteger(789221)))
                                      .add(new BigInteger(1376312589));
```

=> test = 0

Comment: What happens if you declare `n` as `long` in the Java example?

Comment: then i get -1448455493533196867

Comment: try parse long parse int rather than implicit var

Comment: Try using `double` (Or `BigInteger`, if you want an exact result)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, as stated by @ajb, is that JavaScript is loosely-typed and is performing double-precision floating-point arithmetic, whereas we need strict 32-bit integer arithmetic.

For multiplication, the function [`Math.imul`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/imul) exists for this purpose. It is not yet supported in Internet Explorer, but the linked page contains a replacement function that simulates `imul` for older browsers, which works by multiplying the top and bottom halves of the numbers separately.

For addition, we can OR the numbers with 0. This works because any bitwise operation forces JavaScript numbers to become 32-bit integers, and ORing with 0 doesn't actually change the value beyond that:

```javascript
Math.iadd = function(a, b) { return ((a|0) + (b|0))|0; }
```

Now to use it:

```javascript
var n = Math.iadd(4451, Math.imul(554, 57));
n = n << 13 ^ n;
console.log(Math.iadd(Math.imul(n, Math.iadd(Math.imul(Math.imul(n, n), 15731), 789221)), 1376312589));
```

A little bit long and messy, but it works. The output is 587046333, identical to Java.

Comment: Thanks for this, i upvoted and will check it out soon. Might be more performant then the extra library

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript does not have integer arithmetic, and all numbers are stored as 64-bit floats (`double` in Java).  When JavaScript sees a bit-handling operator like `<<` or `^`, it temporarily converts the operands to 32-bit integers to perform the arithmetic, but then converts them back to 64-bit float.  Thus, the last multiplication is performed as a floating-point operation in JavaScript.  In Java, it is still an integer operation.  This code performs the same operation in Java (I have now tested it, and the result is the same):

```
int n = 4451 + 554 * 57;
n = n << 13 ^ n;
double x = n;
System.out.println(x * (x * x * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589);
```

If you want JavaScript code that works the same as Java, you will need a way to perform multiplication and addition that works the same way as Java does when you overflow.  That is, it must treat the results of all operations as if they were in the range -2<sup>31</sup> and 2<sup>31</sup>-1.  There really isn't a reliable way to do this in JavaScript using its native arithmetic; even if you give it two values that have only 31 significant bits, when you multiply them you will get 62 significant bits, while JavaScript's "number" type only has 52 bits, which means some bits will get lost.  There may be a JavaScript library that would allow you to do this kind of exact integer arithmetic, but I'm not an expert on JavaScript frameworks so I don't know what that would be.  Maybe someone else will chime in.

Comment: You are correct about this, now it is identical to the javascript outcome, however i need the other way around :) (javascript out come should be 587046333)

Comment: @CaptainObvious I've edited my answer, but unfortunately it won't be of much help.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the other information anyways ;) i'll try to figure out if i can do this, because it's crucial for my application :)

Comment: I've tried it but without success (i've updated the question with it)

Comment: FWIW the calculation first starts to go awry at `n * n`. In Java, `295120061 * 295120061` correctly results in `-389577847`. In JavaScript, even with [forced integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428136/javascript-integer-math-incorrect-results), `(295120061 * 295120061) | 0` incorrectly results in `-389577840`. It compounds from there, with other similar added inaccuracies.

Comment: @CaptainObvious If you post how you got it working, it could help others who are also trying to perform accurate integer math in JavaScript.

Comment: "There may be a JavaScript library that would allow you to do this kind of exact integer arithmetic," There is! See my answer below!

Answer (score 1):

Using: https://github.com/iriscouch/bigdecimal.js

```
var n = 4451 + 554 * 57; 
n=n << 13 ^ n; 
var test = new BigDecimal(n).multiply( new BigDecimal(n) 
                                      .multiply(new BigDecimal(n)) 
                                      .multiply(new BigDecimal(15731)) 
                                      .add(new BigDecimal(789221)))
                                      .add(new BigDecimal(1376312589));
    test.intValue()
```

prints the correct result